# Save NSArray of UIImages to disk

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

Im wondering if its possible to save an array which contains UIImages to the disk on the ipad? My idea is not to save them image per image as PNG or JPG on a folder. Is there any possibility to save the whole array and load it later?

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible if instead of UImage you keep array of NSData and than create images from those NSData objects but I guess it's not what you want

Comment: Mh no, I think that can be the solution, because I have the possibility to hold the NSDate in my array instead of the UIImage. Than it should be possible with [myNSDataArray writeToFile:...]?:)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
for(UIImage* img in image_array) {
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@(%d)", path, i++] atomically: YES];
}
```

Comment: mh, thats not the way i want to do it. Because I think I lose information when I use UIImagePNGRepresentation, or not? Otherwise I would save an array of NSData and write it to file.